# compress 2-bit numbers and save 1 bit use compression scheme

Tags: algorithm, math, compression, proof

I want to create a compression scheme for 2-bit numbers such that it will reduce the size of any sequence by at least one bit.  How can I prove this is not possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible to always reduce the size by one bit.  What is impossible is losslessly reversing the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4 possible two-bit numbers and 3 possible shorter bit sequences (the empty sequence of bits and the sequences 0 and 1).  By the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), this means that any mapping from two-bit sequences to shorter sequences must have at least two sequences compressed to the same shorter sequence.  As a result, when you want to decompress this shorter sequence, you will not be able to do so because you won't know which of the original two-bit sequences it came from.

This can be generalized to show that n-bit sequences cannot be losslessly compressed to bit sequences of length less than n.  [This earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6526266/501557) details why this is.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You mean "...must have at least two sequences compressed to _the same_ shorter sequence", I think. (Obvious to anyone who already knows the argument, but perhaps not obvious to a new reader.)

Comment: @templatetypedef In most cases if you compress things you have to get rid of stuff, then how could you compress anything and bring back to the original form?

Comment: @benbar- In many cases data is highly redundant and it's possible to compress the data by eliminating the redundancy