# What is the optimum known upper bound on Kolmogorov complexity?

Tags: algorithm, compression, computation-theory, information-theory

Given [infinite time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3523170/5495432), we could approach a string's exact [Kolmogorov complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6526266/5495432). If we don't have infinite time, we can still calculate an upper bound on the Kolmogorov complexity of a string:

> ...simply compress the string s with some method, implement the corresponding decompressor in the chosen language, concatenate the decompressor to the compressed string, and measure the length of the resulting string...[(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Compression)

Is there an algorithm--guaranteed to terminate within a finite amount of time--that provides a tighter upper bound on Kolmogorov complexity than `len(compressed string)  + len(decompressor)`?

Comment: Define *compression*. It's just a non-length-preserving transformation. Of course there are other approaches/transformations and it's your call if you would call it compression. Compression algorithms are just a natural thing (everyone knows) which are widely used in practice.

Comment: For the purposes of this question, I'll go with a generic definition of compression. Let compression (`C(s) = s'`) and decompression (`D(s') = s`) be functions mapping strings to strings. So, is there a better upper bound to the Kolmogorov complexity of `s` than `s' + len(D)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, K(x) is not approximable. There is no upper bound. Consider compressing pi. There exists a small program that produces pi,  so K(pi)  is very small. But "standard" compression programs (zip, etc...) can't compress pi much. So compress(pi) is large -- arbitrarily large. Hence compress(pi) - K(pi) is unbounded.

Put another way: we don't know how small K(x) could be so we can't place an upper bound on an approximation.